# Cant able to delete a file in SD card using file connection -- Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I have developed a blackberry app in which i have video control to capture image then i save the images in the root directory in my desired name and displaying the the screen... in the re-capture button click i am again capturing the image once again and i am deleting the previous image and saving the new image in the same name in the same path using the file connection. My problem is its works fine in emulator. But when i tested in device, it throws me error when i try to delete the previous image to save the new image.. it throws "net.rim.device.api.io.file.fileioexception: the file is currently in use" .. please help me..

---

@arhimed, @juanmabaiu
This is the function where it goes to catch and throws exception when tested in device.

```
 public void fieldChanged( final byte[] _raw )
{
    try
    {    
        flag ++;
        // Create the connection to a file that may or
        // may not exist.
        FileConnection file = (FileConnection)Connector.open(FILE_NAME + "_front" + EXTENSION);

        // If the file exists, increment the counter until we find
        // one that hasn't been created yet.
        while( file.exists() )
        {
            file.delete();
            file = (FileConnection)Connector.open( FILE_NAME + "_front" + EXTENSION );
        }          

        //FileConnection file_temp = (FileConnection)Connector.open(FILE_NAME + "tempimg" + EXTENSION);
        //file_temp.delete();
        // We know the file doesn't exist yet, so create it
        file.create();

        // Write the image to the file
        OutputStream out = file.openOutputStream();
        out.write(_raw);

        // Close the connections
        out.close();
        file.close();
        //Dialog.inform( "Saved to " + FILE_NAME + "_front" + EXTENSION );
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        home.errorDialog("ERROR " + e.getClass() + ":  " + e.getMessage());
        Dialog.inform( "File not saved this time");
    }        
}
```

Comment: Make sure you've closed any streams after you saved or deleted the file.

Comment: Try what Arhimed said in above comment.
If it doesn't fix it please add some code.

Comment: hi arhimed and juanmabaiu.. everything is fine in code.. its working perfectly in emulator. its showing error when tested in device only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code is smelly:

```
while( file.exists() )
{
    file.delete();
    file = (FileConnection)Connector.open( FILE_NAME + "_front" + EXTENSION );
}
```

In fact if file exists, then you delete it, but you forget about the `FileConnection` instance for the just deleted file. I think this could be the reason. You need to close the `FileConnection` instance immediately. Here is what [BB API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html) says about this:

> Similarly, files or directories can be deleted using the FileConnection.delete() method, and developers should close the connection immediately after deletion to prevent exceptions from accessing a connection to a non-existent file or directory.

So try to use the following:

```
if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
    file.close();
    file = (FileConnection) Connector.open(FILE_NAME + "_front" + EXTENSION);
}
```

Another point to highlight is that the code is very self-confident/optimistic, it does not properly handle corner cases. E.g. what if `out.write(_raw);` fails by what ever reason (no free space available, for instance)? Will the FileConnection and OutputStream be closed? No. So you need to add a `finally` block where you make sure you actually does not leave anything open.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried what you have said. But still i am facing the same issue.

Comment: Something definitelly holds system resources for that file. Try to figure out what exactly does it.

Comment: the above if loop also works perfectly in the emulator and throws exception in device.. If you want i can mail my entire code to you. can you help me in this issue ?

Comment: Sorry man, unfortunatelly I'll not be able to process your email request.

Answer (score 2):

I also facing this issue, but when i tried to save image on device memory rather than SDcard. The following code is able to delete the image:

```
if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
    file.close();
}
```